# Machine learning and SVM

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Hello everyone i am struggling with machine learning, still a beginner 
I want to ask if we want to fit our svm model should we write

```
svm_clf_sentanalysis=sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel="linear",gamma='auto')
svm_clf_sentanalysis.fit(X_train_sentanalysis,Y_train_sentanalysis,X_train_sentanalysis_punc,Y_train_sentanalysis_punc)
```

or fit the `svm_clf_sentanalysis` two times once for `X_train_sentanalysis,Y_train_sentanalysis`
and other for `X_train_sentanalysis_punc,Y_train_sentanalysis_punc`

I also encountered `TypeError: fit() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given, when including my three features in fit.`
please provide assistance.

Comment: clf.fit(X_train, y_train) is the basic concept for training every algorithm so first approach won't work as suggested by the error. And how could you possibly have 2 y_train?

Comment: did you read documentation or any tutorial ?

Comment: You are passing parameters to `svc.fit()` that are not allowed. The fit method takes in X, y and a `sample_weight` parameter...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming X_train_sentanalysis_punc,Y_train_sentanalysis_punc are the dataframes used for testing.
You should pass X_train_sentanalysis,Y_train_sentanalysis into the .fit() function for training.

i.e., `svm_clf_sentanalysis.fit(X_train_sentanalysis,Y_train_sentanalysis)`

And for testing, you should use .score() function.

i.e., `svm_clf_sentanalysis.score(X_train_sentanalysis_punc,Y_train_sentanalysis_punc)`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Hope this helps you. In Machine Learning, training an ML model is more like teaching a kid. You first tell this kid, what is Apple, Ball, Cat,.. and then ask the questions. The same analogy here.

- X_train_sentanalysis: supposed to the questions
- Y_train_sentanalysis: supposed to the questions answers
- X_train_sentanalysis_punc: supposed to the exam questions
- Y_train_sentanalysis_punc: : supposed to the exam questions answers

**First train you ML Model**

```
svm_clf_sentanalysis.fit(X_train_sentanalysis,Y_train_sentanalysis)
```

**Now test your ML model**

```
svm_clf_sentanalysis.score(X_train_sentanalysis_punc, Y_train_sentanalysis_punc)
```